# Loop differential equation involving latency

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

I am trying to find out what the solution is for the following differential equation:

```
y'(t) = K y(t-a)
```

where `K` is a constant and `a` is a latency parameter.

This equation describes a positive feedback loop in time after an `a` latency.

So far, I know that for no latency, `a=0`, the equation has an exponential solution like this

```
y(t) = exp(Kt + C1)
```

where

```
C1 = ln(y(0))
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This is called a delay differential equation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation)

Comment: Thank you Raskolnikov. I see this is a complex field, with a general DDE equation way more complex than mine. Any hint to get a simple approach for my equation, not having dependency neither in the current state nor in t?

Comment: If you send actual data for the parameters, the interval where you want a solution and other details I can try and solve it numerically with *Mathematica*

Comment: Thank you Raffaele, but I was trying to find an analytical expression, which I guess is not the case for what I am learning about DDEs.

Comment: @coterobarros : If you look attentively at the section "solving DDEs", the example that is being solved is exactly the one you ask for.

Comment: Yes! Thank you @Raskolnikov